# Problem with local development for google-oauth / calendar api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, google-oauth

I "just" want to integrate google calendar api to my little web project. The user should be able to add calendar entries to his calendar - via a c# core (2.2) mvc project. The problem is I can't find any complete example how to do this and tried a lot without any solution.

The main problem - how can I get the permission? And how can I set the redirect url?

Why google does not provide a complete example für c# core?

I build a simple console projekt (based on an example) - that works if I set the permission manually. But I must ask my user to give the permission.

Btw - I created and saved the ClientId, ClientSecret and so on at/from https://console.developers.google.com/.

Thanks Ralf

```cs
 public IActionResult GoogleCalendar(string id)
        {

            string refreshToken = string.Empty;
            string credentialError;
            var credential = GetUserCredential(out credentialError);
            if (credential != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(credentialError))
            {
                //Save RefreshToken into Database 
                refreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
            }

            string addEventError;
            string calendarEventId = string.Empty;

            calendarEventId = AddCalenderEvents(refreshToken, "mytestuser@googlemail.com", "Test-Event " + DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), out addEventError);

            return View();
        }


public static UserCredential GetUserCredential(out string error)
        {
            UserCredential credential = null;
            error = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = ClientSecret
                },
                Scopes,
                "mytestuser@googlemail.com",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("Google Oauth2 Client App")).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                credential = null;
                error = "Failed to UserCredential Initialization: " + ex.ToString();
            }

            return credential;
        }
```

I get from google

401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

On a (changing) local port an url I have never set.

```
access_type=offline
response_type=code
client_id=xxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:56253/authorize/
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided samples from google are quite confusing, the provided console demo application only works for local environments because it tries to launch the browser and use it to authenticatie.

To authenticatie users on a web app, check the following google guide: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc